# Python 3.4 syntax errors from using print function

Tags: python

I'm running files obtained from the web in my desktop's Python 3.4 install, and getting syntax errors, such as:

```
class MyClient(IBCpp.IBClient):
  def setup(self):
    self.stime=None
    self.nextId=0
#        self.symbol='STK.AAPL'
#        self.symbol='CASH.EUR.USD'
    self.symbol='FUT.ES.USD.201506'

    self.state='first'
```

skipping a few defs which aren't pre-requisite, there's:

```
 def orderStatus(self,orderId, status, filled, remaining, avgFillPrice,
 permId, parentId, lastFillPrice, clientId, whyHeld):
    """
    call back function of IB C++ API which update status or certain order
    indicated by orderId
    """
    print self.symbol, status, 'filled=',filled, 'remaining=', remaining'
```

for which the interpreter responds

```
print self.symbol, status, 'filled=',filled, 'remaining=', remaining
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is this perhaps due to a difference of 2.7 vs 3.4? I'm not sure what version the source file was created in. Source is from [IBridgePy github repo](https://github.com/IBridgePy)

Comment: As of Python 3, `print` is now a function. Use `print()` like this: `print('hello world')`.

Answer (score 0):

[Check the Python 3 docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Python 3 uses `()` around the print contents - `print ('python')`